# YAML File not loading with nested values

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am writing a YAML parser in python using ruamel.yaml
Reason for ruamel.yaml is it maintains comments which are key!

I know the issue is caused with the YAML file, and I am not sure on how to overcome this issue, or what a potential modification is. I have tried a few variations of indentation, but have struck out.

Keeping it simple, passing in source and trying to load it.

Code:

```
import os
import os.path
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

def main():
    source = "my_yaml.yml"
    # Check if the source fil is valid yaml
    try:
        yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
        with open(source) as fp:
            # data is the file data and will be used down the line
            data = yaml.load(fp)

        if data is None:
            data = {}
        return data
    except:
        print("Yaml file is not valid. Please check the source.")
        return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    out = main()
```

YAML that works:

```
d1: "key1"
d2: "key2"
d3: 
  d3_nest1: "key3"
  d3_nest2: "key4"
```

YAML that does not work:

```
d1: "key1"
d2: "key2"
d3: 
  d3_nest1: "key3"
  d3_nest2: "key4"
  # this next item breaks my yaml
  - d3_nest3: "key6"
  d3_nest4: "key7"
```

Other Variations of YAML:

```
d1: "key1"
d2: "key2"
d3: 
    d3_nest1: "key4"
    d3_nest2: "key5"
# this next item breaks my yaml
- d3_nest3: "key6"
    d3_nest4: "key7"

d1: "key1"
d2: "key2"
d3: 
    d3_nest1: "key4"
    d3_nest2: "key5"
# this next item breaks my yaml
    - d3_nest3: "key6"
        d3_nest4: "key7"
```

Comment: Your first example is invalid YAML as well, and throws an error in ruamel.yaml. Are you sure you copy and pasted it?

Comment: @Anthon I moused over an old set of yaml, please see updates.

Comment: Yes that makes the first one loadable. The others mix sequence elements with mapping key-values. You can't do that. You'll need to remove e.g. `"key4" so that `- d3_nest3: "key6"` will be the value for `d3_nest2` (i.e. a single element sequence whose element is a mapping that is a single key-value pair ( `d3_nest3`: `key6`))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:
d3_nest2: key5
- d3_nest3: key6
d3_nest4: key7

is invalid YAML because once you start a block style mapping, every line
needs to be of the form `key: value` until you change the indentation.

It is unclear what you want to achieve with providing a sequence element in the middle of a mapping, just as you cannot have a Python `dict` behave as a sequence for the 2nd element only. Maybe you want the following:

```
d1: "key1"
d2: "key2"
d3: 
  d3_nest1: "key3"
  d3_nest2:         # "key4" removed
  - d3_nest3: "key6"
  d3_nest4: "key7"
```

I recommend you create the data structure you want to have in Python (using nested dicts,lists and strings values), assuming you are more familiar with that, and then dump using `ruamel.yaml` so you'll get  a better idea of what is correct YAML syntax.

The recommended extension for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml` for over 15 years.

Comment: Thank you for a bit of insight here, I will go about the data structure in python .